# How to change ubuntu to root?

Tags: linux, permissions, operating-system

I am new to linux. when i list the files under folder 1, i see below result

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root   root      920 Jun  3 10:36 file1.xsd
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root   root      920 Jun  3 10:36 file2.xsd
drwxrwxrwx 2 ubuntu ubuntu   4096 Jun 12 11:10 temp
-rwxrwxrwx 1 ubuntu ubuntu   1853 Jun 19 11:07 file3.xsd
```

for some files(file1 and file2) root root is written after permisionsbut for file3  ubuntu ubuntu is displayed.

what is difference b/w  ubuntu ubuntu and root root ?

How can i change ubuntu ubuntu for file 3 to root root ?

Comment: you might want to look into chown command of linux

Comment: The two columns show the ownership of the file: user "root", file "root", ...

Comment: A hint: it makes more sense to ask such question over at the "SuperUser" sister page. You can see the link at the bottom of this page in the footer. Reason is that _this_ page is all about _programming_ questions.

Comment: i understand first is user (i.e root user)  but what is second root.You said file "root  what does it mean ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first "root" stands for user name and second "root" stands for the group name. By design, Ubuntu uses "sudo" command to run other commands "as root", and the actual root user is not used.

So what that means, every time you use the command sudo to run a command, it is actually being done as root. That's most likely the reason for the two of your files being owned by root (and the group root).

You can change the ownership of the file with command chown:

```
chown root:root file3.xsd
```